# Error #1056: Cannot create property solidLevel on Main

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an empty class called `solidLevel` which is used to identify any 'solid' objects. The main object is, for now, declared as a static object in the `Main` class:

```
public static var platformLevel:platformMap;
public static var solidLevel:solidMap;
```

I also made a map for platforms. And both have their specific objects, named `platformLevel` and `solidLevel`, which are both instantiated in the main room, and are both linked to their respective empty classes. `platformMap` and `solidMap`.

I tried to turn on and off the '*Automatically Declare Stage Instances*', but the issue with that is that I have at least one such instance whose x-y coordinates I need, and if I tick the option off in the settings, then I cannot refer to that object for position anymore (There's probably a smarter way to make x-y coordinates correspond between the code and the visualized stage?).

I'm wondering if it is an issue that my variable is `Static`. Maybe the compiler sees a difference between `Main.solidLevel` and the `solidLevel` that I did in the stage?
At any rate, I need the variables to be global, so there has got to be a way to work around that.

The code that doesn't work looks like this:

```
public function Main() 
{
    Main.platformLevel = new platformMap();
    Main.platformLevel.x = 10;
    Main.platformLevel.y = 10;
    stage.addChild(Main.platformLevel);

    Main.solidLevel = new solidMap();
    Main.solidLevel.x = 10;
    Main.solidLevel.y = 10;
    stage.addChild(Main.solidLevel);
    ...
}
```

It's probably interesting to note that the SECOND block is the issue, and not the first one, whereas they are near identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared the reference as `solidLevel`, but you are trying to access to `solidNiveau`.

**Edit:**
The error occurs whenever you try to access a property which's inaccessible from where you want to access it.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that; I... tried translating the variables' name upon asking the question. Probably not very smart of me. Needless to say, this is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @Edit: Yes, but why would it be inaccessible? I don't really know what is wrong at all.

Comment: I watched a bunch of tutorials and managed to link my classes appropriately afterwards. It's possible there was a confusion between the instance names, the variables, and the class names (which I had set as the same because I didn't know what went where).
Now all I have is `platformStuff = platformLevel;` (variable = instance, where the both are type `platformMap`) and it works. It seems I have to instantiate all physical objects in the code, or else I have an error concerning inexisting variables.